# Recoding multiple variables in Pandas at once

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a dataframe where some of variables pretty much have the same values. I need to recode them. Is there a more efficient way than what I came up with? For example, in the example below, I need to recode var3, var4 and var10 into 1, 2, 3, 4, if they equal to 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'.

```
testdata = [{'var1' : 'A', 'var3' : 'B', 'var4' : 'C', 'var10' : 'C'}, 
            {'var1' : 'C', 'var3' : 'D', 'var4' : 'A', 'var10' : 'B'}, 
            {'var1' : 'D', 'var3' : 'B', 'var4' : 'B', 'var10' : 'A'}
           ]

df3 = pd.DataFrame(testdata)

cols = df3.columns[1:]

for c in cols:
    df3[c][df3[c] == 'A'] = 1
    df3[c][df3[c] == 'B'] = 2
    df3[c][df3[c] == 'C'] = 3
    df3[c][df3[c] == 'D'] = 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iloc` and `replace` using a `dict` i.e

```
df3.iloc[:,1:] = df3.iloc[:,1:].replace({'A':1,'B':2,'C':3,'D':4})
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you can `stack` and then replace with `Series.map`.

```
repl_dict = {'A' : 1,'B' : 2,'C' : 3,'D' : 4}
(df3.set_index('var1')
    .stack()
    .map(repl_dict)
    .unstack()
    .reset_index()
)

  var1  var10  var3  var4
0    A      3     2     3
1    C      2     4     1
2    D      1     2     2
```

---

Or, use `pd.factorize`:

```
v = df3.set_index('var1').stack()
v[:] = pd.factorize(v)[0] + 1
v.unstack().reset_index()

  var1  var10  var3  var4
0    A      1     2     1
1    C      2     3     4
2    D      4     2     2
```

Which bypasses the need for a `repl_dict` and scales to thousands of values. 
Though of course the label encodings are entirely upto `pd.factorize` now...